# HTML dropdown with ng-options binding does not work with angular-dart

Tags: dart, angular-dart

Angular-dart ng-options does not seems to be working.

```
  <select ng-model="selectedOption" ng-options="s.DisplayText for s in myOptions">
        <option value="">Select Option</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Where did you get this syntax from? `"s.DisplayText for s in myOptions"` What should the result of this be?

Comment: We can write this kind of syntax in angularjs. I think angulardart is port angularjs and it will have ng-options binding.

Comment: Angular.dart isn't a port of Angular.js. Angular.dart is a new implementation. You can see Angular.dart as prototype for Angular 2.

Comment: What is the equivalent of this in angulardart?

Comment: I guess ng-repeat, but it's a while I worked with Angular.

Comment: ng-repeat is not helping me. I want "Select Option" static option always displayed at the top in dropdown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<select ng-model="selectedOptionId">
        <option value="">Select Option</option>
        <option ng-repeat="o in myOptions" value="{{o.id}}">
                    {{o.DisplayText}}
        </option>
</select>
```

Note that selectedOptionId is string, if we use myOption(type with id and DisplayText as properties) as model it will add new option with "?" in HTML.